# How to group and aggregate two lists in Python or Scala?

Tags: python, list, scala, aggregate, grouping

Given input lists:

```
L1 = [("A","p1",20), ("B","p2",30)]
L2 = [("A","p1",100), ("c","p3",35)]
```

Expected output:

```
[(A,p1,20,100), (B,p2,30,"not in L2"), ("c","p3",35,"not in L1")]
```

I have tried using two `for` loops one for `L1` and other for `L2` but it is not working for iterative elements and giving repeated output which is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a dictionary holding all possible grouping keys (`"A","p1"`, `"B","p2"`, etc.). Then, loop through keys in this dictionary to find if it exists in either of the lists.

```py
L1 = [("A","p1",20), ("B","p2",30)]
L2 = [("A","p1",100), ("c","p3",35)]


d = {}
for x, y, z in L1 + L2:
    d[(x, y)] = [z] if not d.get((x, y)) else d[(x, y)] + [z]
for k in d:
    if k not in {(x, y) for x, y, z in L1}:
        d[k] += ["not in L1"]
    if k not in {(x, y) for x, y, z in L2}:
        d[k] += ["not in L2"]
L = [(*k, *v) for k, v in d.items()]

print(L)
# [('A', 'p1', 20, 100), ('B', 'p2', 30, 'not in L2'), ('c', 'p3', 35, 'not in L1')]
```

This would be safe if you had doubled keys in one list:

```py
L1 = [("A","p1",20), ("B","p2",30)]
L2 = [("A","p1",100), ("A","p1",200), ("c","p3",35)]
```

Then the result would be

```
# [('A', 'p1', 20, 100, 200), ('B', 'p2', 30, 'not in L2'), ('c', 'p3', 35, 'not in L1')]
```

---

For more lists:

```py
L1 = [("A","p1",20), ("B","p2",30)]
L2 = [("A","p1",100), ("c","p3",35)]
L3 = [("A","p1",200)]


d = {}
lists = ["L1", "L2", "L3"]
for x, y, z in [x for lst in lists for x in eval(lst)]:
    d[(x, y)] = [z] if not d.get((x, y)) else d[(x, y)] + [z]
for k in d:
    for lst in lists:
        if k not in {(x, y) for x, y, z in eval(lst)}:
            d[k] += [f"not in {lst}"]
L = [(*k, *v) for k, v in d.items()]

print(L)
# [('A', 'p1', 20, 100, 200), ('B', 'p2', 30, 'not in L2', 'not in L3'), ('c', 'p3', 35, 'not in L1', 'not in L3')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L1 = [("A","p1",20), ("B","p2",30)]
L2 = [("A","p1",100), ("c","p3",35)]

# tranform L1, L2 to dict
D1 = dict((_[0], _) for _ in L1)
D2 = dict((_[0], _) for _ in L2)
out_dict = dict()

for k, v in D1.items():
    if k in D2:
        # use set to avoid duplicated value
        new_tuple = D2[k] + v
        # keep the original order
        sorted_list = sorted(set(new_tuple), key=new_tuple.index)
        out_dict[k] = tuple(sorted_list)
    else:
        out_dict[k] = v + ("not in L2",)

for k, v in D2.items():
    if k in D1:
        new_tuple = D1[k] + v
        sorted_list = sorted(set(new_tuple), key=new_tuple.index)
        out_dict[k] = tuple(sorted_list)
    else:
        out_dict[k] = v + ("not in L1",)

output = list(v for k, v in out_dict.items())
```

Output:

```
[('A', 'p1', 20, 100),
 ('B', 'p2', 30, 'not in L2'),
 ('c', 'p3', 35, 'not in L1')]
```

Comment: it's working fine for given two list. But if I add more number of list as a input will this logic works with some changes ?